# Use SUMPRODUCT to Count with Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Trying to get a Sumproduct to evaluate and count data contained in multiple columns on same worksheet.

- `Column "A"` should not be blank
- `Column "B"` has a 2016 `date` value and looking to report by each calendar month
- `Column "E"` should not be blank
- `Column "AD"` should be counted so long as `Column "E"` has a value in same row.
- The text "Loss" is not present in `column "AD"`

Correct count for the below example would be three (3)!

[image]

Here's what I came up with so far, but isn't working:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR('Sheet1'!$B3:$B502)=2016)*(MONTH('sheet1'!$B3:$B502)=5)*('sheet1'!$E3:$E502<>""))-(('sheet1'!$AD3:$AD502)<>"Loss")}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: If you are reporting for a particular calendar month then Correct count for the example would be two (2) for the month of March. Please clarify.

Comment: I am waiting for the pending edits to show so the logic statements can be layes out as bullet points or at least separate lines

Comment: Correct count for March is only one (1) as column AD4 has the text "Loss" and should not be counted at all regardless of what's in column E.

Comment: when presenting data in a question, a sample of copy and pasteable text data is preferred over a screen shot.  [Consider using a sight like this to convert excel tables to ascii table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: Feb = 1;  March = 1;  and May = 1  for a YTD total of three (3) in this simplistic example.

Comment: you statement of "Column "E" should not be blank " and "Column "AD" should be counted so long as Column "E" has a value in same row" is redundant if I understand things right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A2:$A7<>"")*(YEAR($B2:$B7)=2016)*($C2:$C7<>"")*($D2:$D7<>"Loss"))
```

That should count the number of entire rows where:

A is not empty
B is year 2016
E is not empty
AD is not loss

Only when ALL those condition are true will a row be counted.  The above formula is in H1.

If you want a monthly breakdown you need to put in a condition to count each month.  So in G1 I used the following formula and copied down 12 rows.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7<>"")*(YEAR($B$2:$B$7)=2016)*($C$2:$C$7<>"")*($D$2:$D$7<>"Loss")*(MONTH($B$2:$B$7)=ROW(A1)))
```

Row(A1) is acting as a counter.

Proof of concept

[image]

Comment: It works for the year, but I need it broken out by each calendar month.

Comment: Figured it out...Thanks Forward Ed!

Comment: it was not originally broken out for each month as you said in your previous comments that the answer was three cause you were grouping your months together

Comment: Thank you Forward Ed - Works perfectly!